# Scraping HTML Tables with rowspan attributes using node and cheerio.js

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape an HTML table from wikipedia for data however I'm having alot of trouble traversing the table due to the rowspan attributes. I'm using the cheerio package and am getting lost in the amount of jQuery objects that cheerio returns. Any help would be really appreciated, I've been banging my head against this for days. What you see below is only a fraction of the code i've attempted to use. Thank you

Table URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_bibliography"

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const $ = require("cheerio");

const WIKI_URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_bibliography";

const getBooks = async (url) => {
  const scrapedBooks = [];
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const htmlParse = $(
      "#mw-content-text > div.mw-parser-output > table:nth-child(6) > tbody > tr",
      res.data
    );
    // let filtData = [];
    // for (let i = 0; i < htmlParse.length; i++) {
    //   filtData.push(
    //     htmlParse[i].children.filter((child) => child.data !== "\n")
    //   );
    // }
    // htmlParse[i].children[5].attribs["rowspan"]

//Getting the Row headers
    let headers = [];
    htmlParse.each((index, el) => {
      headers.push(
        $(el)
          .find("th")
          .text()
          .split("\n")
          .filter((item) => item.length)
      );
    });
    headers = headers[0];

    let data = [];

    htmlParse.each((index, el) => {
      let item = $(el).find("td");
      item.attr("rowspan") ? data.push(item.get()) : data.push("NOT FOUND");
    });

    console.log(data);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

getBooks(WIKI_URL);
```

Comment: rowspan is a range, push the same data for every row and subtract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried web **scraping** before but I've been wanting to get into it, so I gave this problem a shot.

Your problem, as I understand it, is that the rowspan is throwing off the number of cells per row in a table, which is leading to some rows having less than a consistent 6 items of data.

Since I took a fresh approach, the code isn't the same, but it does work with your  url, uses the same package, and resolves your specific problem. See below code for a working version. I added my own comments to help you understand what is happening.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
// parses HTML
var $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
// targets the specific with selectors
var html_table = $('#mw-content-text > div.mw-parser-output > table:nth-child(6)');
// gets table header titles; loops through all th data, and pulls an array of the values
var table_header = html_table.find('th').map(function() {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
// gets all rowspans inside the table; loops through all tr rows
var rowspans = html_table.find('tbody tr').map(function(tr_index) {
  // gets all rowspans for the current row; loops through all td cells of the current tr row
  var tr_rowspans = $(this).find('td').map(function(td_index) {
    // shotern the reference to the rowspan value of the current td cell since it's used more than once
    var rowspan_count = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    // build an object with the index of the current tr, td, the rowspan value, and the the td value
    return {'tr_index':tr_index, 'td_index':rowspan_count ? td_index : 0, 'count':Number(rowspan_count) || 0, 'value':$(this).text().trim()};
  }).toArray().filter(function(item) {return item.count;});
  // the filter above ^ removes undefined items form the array
  // returns the rowspans for the current row
  return tr_rowspans;
}).toArray();
// gets table cell values; loops through all tr rows
var table_data = html_table.find('tbody tr').map(function(tr_index) {
  // gets the cells value for the row; loops through each cell and returns an array of values
  // note: nothing special happens to the cells at this point
  var cells = $(this).find('td').map(function(td_index) {return $(this).text().trim();}).toArray();
  // adds missing cells to each row of data; loops through each rowspan collected
  rowspans.forEach(function(rowspan) {
    // defines the min and max rows; uses tr index to get the first index, and tr index + rowspan value to get the last index
    var span = {'min':rowspan.tr_index, 'max':rowspan.tr_index + rowspan.count};
    // if the current row is within the min and max
    if (tr_index > span.min && tr_index < span.max) {
      // add an array element where the missing cell data should be and add the cell value at the same time
      cells.splice(rowspan.td_index, 0, rowspan.value);
    }
  });
  // returns an array of the cell data generated
  return [cells];
}).toArray();
// output the table headers
console.log('table_header', table_header);
// output the table data
console.log('table_data', table_data);
```